# New issues in PDO Class

Tags: php, pdo

I have a code which connect my DB class.

```
<?php
require('DB.php');
$pdo = new PDO(
'mysql:dbname=MYDB;host=localhost',
'MYUSER',
'MYPASS',
array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
)
);
DB::$c = $pdo;
?>


MY DB.php is here http://pastebin.com/VjNNVbCm
```

This code was working fine till last day. Now i see a error message. See the log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: DB::$c in /home/domain/  .... /inc/config.php on line 13
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear... does the static property c exist in your DB class?

Comment: Yes its like class DB
{
 static $q,$c,$p,$i = '`';

Comment: You should use a method if you want to change the value of a static property.

Comment: PDO has nothing much to do with the error. We cannot confirm or deny the workings of this code, because the crucial `DB` class is not shown here.

Comment: stackoverflow needs to make sure people know how to ask question. i got tired of posting again and again helpfull comments on how to ask. [useless rant end.]

Comment: I pasted the class here http://pastebin.com/VjNNVbCm its a PDO based class i got for from net. Which i am using. The code won't show any issues till last day..

Comment: @Masiorama How i rewrite it?

Comment: You said it worked till yesterday... what did you change? Did you upgrade anything?

Comment: No. I won't made any  changes, I checked with hosting provider they said they don't upgrade anything.

Comment: Anyone have any input?

Comment: Any change in your library, in the way you use it or any upgrades to PHP or in the configuration of PHP may cause this. But instead of focusing on why it happens *now*, I'd focus on why it happens at all and solve that. Also, it's a bit inpolite to bump the question if you didn't get a response in 45 minutes. Some people have jobs, you know.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I am looking to the issues from morning i don't find any clues yet. My customer is calling me since its a live site.

Comment: Is that code in the 'pastebin' link taken from the live site or is it your local copy? i.e. Have you checked the code that is actually on the live site. The `DB` class  in 'pastebin' works here.

Comment: Thank you your effort to fix. But yes this is same copy from server. I pasted.

Comment: I am using this script: https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is solved by upgrading PHP in to 5.5 .